# JTable contents and database table in one report

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I am new to JasprReports. I learned to get JTable contents to JasperReport using,

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), new JRTableModelDataSource(table.getModel()));
```

and get Oracle SQL contents to the report using,

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), connection);
```

My question is, is it possible to get both of them in one report?

For example, I have JTable contents as following:

```
EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, EMP_SALARY
```

which is the main content of the table and I want something in the header from a SQL table Department

```
Department_no, Department_Name
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround...

I am getting the contents of the table from database to java using jdbc, and then using params hashmap to pass those contents to report.

Got this idea from [here](http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/creating-a-jasper-report-without-a-datasource/).